# Why do I have data loss using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

On my `ubuntu 10.04` host I use Nokogiri in a Ruby script.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.google.com.hk"))
```

That works fine and I receive data.

On my product host running CentOS 5, it fails. There is no error, it returns a single line of data only.

```
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x43a5332 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x43a5094 name="html">]>
```

Where is the data in `#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x43a5094 name="html">`?

Comment: I doubt any package uninstall on my server...who can help me~~~~~~:`(

Comment: Check both the places with similar target file and this `doc.serialize.size`. If both are equal, you need not to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri uses libxml2 to do much of the heavy lifting. It is probable that you have a bad install of libxml2 on your production environment. Install a clean, updated version of libxml2 and then re-install Nokogiri (ensuring that it uses your new install).

For more information, read *["What to do if libxml2 is being a jerk"](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/what-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be hiding an error from you. Try splitting up your request of the data from the parsing of the data, so you can see what Nokogiri sees:

```
body = open("http://www.google.com.hk").read
puts body
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
```